# Нужно ли тире в предложении перед инфинитивами?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Нужно ли тире в предложении?
**В этом случае только и осталось (—) сесть и заплакать.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В предложении такой структуры тире обозначает паузу: **В этом случае только и остАлось ― сесть и заплакать.**

Возможные варианты:

(1) **Только и осталось** теперь заплакать.

(2) **Только и остАлось** ― сесть и заплакать.

(3) В этом случае только **одно** и осталось ― сесть и заплакать (пояснение к местоимению ***одно***, тире обязательно).

(4) В этом случае **только и осталось, что** сесть и заплакать (запятая перед союзом ЧТО).

**Розенталь (только и… что)** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146  (пункт 9)

Примеры:

Старшина Пономарев сидел на земляном полу под каменным сводом и думал. Ему **только и осталось теперь думать**.  [Г. Я. Бакланов. Южнее главного удара (1957)]

Стало быть, **одно только и осталось ― разорять** помаленьку дом, распродавать по бревнышку… [Евгений Лукин. Катали мы ваше солнце (1997)]

Можно двигаться смело в дальнейший путь. **Только и осталось** ― отход оформить. Ну, уж это я взял на себя. [Андрей Некрасов. Приключения капитана Врунгеля (1960-1980)]

Да уж мне **только и осталось:** либо взвыть голосом от вас, либо песни петь. [А. Н. Островский. Пучина (1865)]

**Только и осталось, что** сидеть-посиживать с удочкой на бережку. [Евгений Руднев. Рассказ об одном утре // «Огонек». № 8, 1959]